# Symfony 5 : on deployment, how to change the public directory?

Tags: php, symfony, deployment, web-deployment

I'm deploying my Symfony application and I'm getting the error:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("Asset manifest file "********/public/build/manifest.json" does not
>   exist.").

My server public dir is www/.

I put `APP_ENV=prod` in my .env file but apparently I'm still in dev environment, is there something else to do to pass on production?

The file exists and is in www/build/manifest.json on the server, how do I change the public dir in Symfony ? I tried to add this in my composer.json file :

```
"extra": {
    "...": "...",
    "public-dir": "www"
}
```

but it didn't work.

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you seen https://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment.html#b-configure-your-environment-variables ? dotenv is usually require-dev so it might not even be present on the server, what is your env setup?

Comment: My .env :

APP_ENV=prod
APP_SECRET=****************
DATABASE_URL=mysql://<db_user>@127.0.0.1:3306/<db_name>?serverVersion=5.7
MAILER_URL=null://localhost

Comment: And my "symfony/dotenv" is in require.

Comment: in that case I'd assume that you have some library using the manifest.json which doesn't respect your changed public-dir. does the `public` dir still exist?